# Get unicode script name in Go

Tags: go, unicode

In Go, I want to get the RangeTable of a script given a specific language.

```
import (
    "golang.org/x/text/language"
    "unicode"
)

...

script, confidence := language.French.Script() 
scriptAsString := script.String() // here scriptAsString = "Latn"
rangeTable, ok := unicode.Scripts[scriptAsString]
// here ok = false, because the Scripts map has key "Latin" and not "Latn"
```

The problem is that the following function returns the [script code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_15924#List_of_codes)

```
func (s Script) String() string
```

Whereas the map `unicode.Scripts` has all of its keys using the [script name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_15924#List_of_codes)

Do you know if there is a way in the native Go lib to go from a `script code` to a `script name`?

**EDIT**:

opened issue here: github.com/golang/go/issues/31862

Comment: I'd grep the source of `golang.org/x/text/language` for a set of sample script names. I'm afraid there may be no such support as the packages under `golang.org/x/text` are primarily targeted at working with Internet protocols which use codes to refer to languages.

Comment: @kostix, thanks, I couldn't really find anything though. Too bad, I feel it creates a kind of inconsistency within the API.

Comment: "Inconsistency" is not correct IMO: it would be a thing if parts the code would use or produce codes and other disparate pieces would do the same with scripts, and there would be difficult to mix and match these parts. But supposedly this is an omission. If these names are standardized, I'm pretty much sure it could be possible to add mapping of codes to script names which would be autogenerated (and hence easily updated when another version of the standard is released). I suggest you to [file an issue](https://github.com/golang/text#report-issues--send-patches) against this package.

Comment: …and if you do this, please post the link to the issue here, thanks!

Comment: @kostix, thanks for the pointers, here's the issue: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/31862

Comment: Please put the `x/text: ` in the issue's title as suggested by the bit I linked to: «…Prefix your issue with "x/text:" in the subject line, so it is easy to find.». Also consider adding a comment linking back to this your question—it could help to provide more context for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of mapping I was after:

```
var scriptCodeToScriptNames = map[string][]string {
    "Adlm": {"Adlam"},
    "Afak": {"Afaka"},
    "Aghb": {"Caucasian_Albanian"},
    "Ahom": {"Ahom"},
    "Arab": {"Arabic"},
    "Aran": {"Arabic"},
    "Armi": {"Imperial_Aramaic"},
    "Armn": {"Armenian"},
    "Avst": {"Avestan"},
    "Bali": {"Balinese"},
    "Bamu": {"Bamum"},
    "Bass": {"Bassa_Vah"},
    "Batk": {"Batak"},
    "Beng": {"Bengali"},
    "Bhks": {"Bhaiksuki"},
    "Bopo": {"Bopomofo"},
    "Brah": {"Brahmi"},
    "Brai": {"Braille"},
    "Bugi": {"Buginese"},
    "Buhd": {"Buhid"},
    "Cakm": {"Chakma"},
    "Cans": {"Canadian_Aboriginal"},
    "Cari": {"Carian"},
    "Cham": {"Cham"},
    "Cher": {"Cherokee"},
    "Copt": {"Coptic"},
    "Cpmn": {"Cypro-Minoan"},
    "Cprt": {"Cypriot"},
    "Cyrl": {"Cyrillic"},
    "Cyrs": {"Cyrillic"},
    "Deva": {"Devanagari"},
    "Dogr": {"Dogra"},
    "Dsrt": {"Deseret"},
    "Dupl": {"Duployan"},
    "Egyd": {"Egyptian_Demotic"},
    "Egyh": {"Egyptian_Hieratic"},
    "Egyp": {"Egyptian_Hieroglyphs"},
    "Elba": {"Elbasan"},
    "Ethi": {"Ethiopic"},
    "Geok": {"Khutsuri"},
    "Geor": {"Georgian"},
    "Glag": {"Glagolitic"},
    "Gong": {"Gunjala_Gondi"},
    "Gonm": {"Masaram_Gondi"},
    "Goth": {"Gothic"},
    "Gran": {"Grantha"},
    "Grek": {"Greek"},
    "Gujr": {"Gujarati"},
    "Guru": {"Gurmukhi"},
    "Hanb": {"Han", "Bopomofo"},
    "Hang": {"Hangul"},
    "Hani": {"Han"},
    "Hano": {"Hanunoo"},
    "Hans": {"Han"},
    "Hant": {"Han"},
    "Hatr": {"Hatran"},
    "Hebr": {"Hebrew"},
    "Hira": {"Hiragana"},
    "Hluw": {"Anatolian_Hieroglyphs"},
    "Hmng": {"Pahawh_Hmong"},
    "Hmnp": {"Nyiakeng_Puachue_Hmong"},
    "Hrkt": {"Hiragana", "Katakana"},
    "Hung": {"Old_Hungarian"},
    "Inds": {"Indus_(Harappan)"},
    "Ital": {"Old_Italic"},
    "Jamo": {"Hangul"},
    "Java": {"Javanese"},
    "Jpan": {"Han", "Hiragana", "Katakana"},
    "Jurc": {"Jurchen"},
    "Kali": {"Kayah_Li"},
    "Kana": {"Katakana"},
    "Khar": {"Kharoshthi"},
    "Khmr": {"Khmer"},
    "Khoj": {"Khojki"},
    "Kitl": {"Khitan_large_script"},
    "Kits": {"Khitan_small_script"},
    "Knda": {"Kannada"},
    "Kore": {"Hangul", "Han"},
    "Kpel": {"Kpelle"},
    "Kthi": {"Kaithi"},
    "Lana": {"Tai_Tham"},
    "Laoo": {"Lao"},
    "Latf": {"Latin"},
    "Latg": {"Latin"},
    "Latn": {"Latin"},
    "Leke": {"Leke"},
    "Lepc": {"Lepcha"},
    "Limb": {"Limbu"},
    "Lina": {"Linear_A"},
    "Linb": {"Linear_B"},
    "Lisu": {"Lisu"},
    "Loma": {"Loma"},
    "Lyci": {"Lycian"},
    "Lydi": {"Lydian"},
    "Mahj": {"Mahajani"},
    "Maka": {"Makasar"},
    "Mand": {"Mandaic"},
    "Mani": {"Manichaean"},
    "Marc": {"Marchen"},
    "Maya": {"Mayan_hieroglyphs"},
    "Mend": {"Mende_Kikakui"},
    "Merc": {"Meroitic_Cursive"},
    "Mero": {"Meroitic_Hieroglyphs"},
    "Mlym": {"Malayalam"},
    "Modi": {"Modi"},
    "Mong": {"Mongolian"},
    "Mroo": {"Mro"},
    "Mtei": {"Meetei_Mayek"},
    "Mult": {"Multani"},
    "Mymr": {"Myanmar"},
    "Narb": {"Old_North_Arabian"},
    "Nbat": {"Nabataean"},
    "Newa": {"Newa"},
    "Nkoo": {"Nko"},
    "Nshu": {"Nushu"},
    "Ogam": {"Ogham"},
    "Olck": {"Ol_Chiki"},
    "Orkh": {"Old_Turkic"},
    "Orya": {"Oriya"},
    "Osge": {"Osage"},
    "Osma": {"Osmanya"},
    "Palm": {"Palmyrene"},
    "Pauc": {"Pau_Cin_Hau"},
    "Perm": {"Old_Permic"},
    "Phag": {"Phags_Pa"},
    "Phli": {"Inscriptional_Pahlavi"},
    "Phlp": {"Psalter_Pahlavi"},
    "Phlv": {"Book_Pahlavi"},
    "Phnx": {"Phoenician"},
    "Plrd": {"Miao"},
    "Prti": {"Inscriptional_Parthian"},
    "Rjng": {"Rejang"},
    "Rohg": {"Hanifi_Rohingya"},
    "Roro": {"Rongorongo"},
    "Runr": {"Runic"},
    "Samr": {"Samaritan"},
    "Sara": {"Sarati"},
    "Sarb": {"Old_South_Arabian"},
    "Saur": {"Saurashtra"},
    "Sgnw": {"SignWriting"},
    "Shaw": {"Shavian"},
    "Shrd": {"Sharada"},
    "Shui": {"Shuishu"},
    "Sidd": {"Siddham"},
    "Sind": {"Khudawadi"},
    "Sinh": {"Sinhala"},
    "Sogd": {"Sogdian"},
    "Sogo": {"Old_Sogdian"},
    "Sora": {"Sora_Sompeng"},
    "Soyo": {"Soyombo"},
    "Sund": {"Sundanese"},
    "Sylo": {"Syloti_Nagri"},
    "Syrc": {"Syriac"},
    "Syre": {"Syriac"},
    "Syrj": {"Syriac"},
    "Syrn": {"Syriac"},
    "Tagb": {"Tagbanwa"},
    "Takr": {"Takri"},
    "Tale": {"Tai_Le"},
    "Talu": {"New_Tai_Lue"},
    "Taml": {"Tamil"},
    "Tang": {"Tangut"},
    "Tavt": {"Tai_Viet"},
    "Telu": {"Telugu"},
    "Teng": {"Tengwar"},
    "Tfng": {"Tifinagh"},
    "Tglg": {"Tagalog"},
    "Thaa": {"Thaana"},
    "Thai": {"Thai"},
    "Tibt": {"Tibetan"},
    "Tirh": {"Tirhuta"},
    "Ugar": {"Ugaritic"},
    "Vaii": {"Vai"},
    "Visp": {"Visible_Speech"},
    "Wara": {"Warang_Citi"},
    "Wcho": {"Wancho"},
    "Wole": {"Woleai"},
    "Xpeo": {"Old_Persian"},
    "Xsux": {"Cuneiform"},
    "Yiii": {"Yi"},
    "Zanb": {"Zanabazar_Square"},
    "Zinh": {"Inherited"},
    "Zyyy": {"Common"},
}
```